# Creating and Arduino synthesizer without the tone library

Tags: arduino-due, sound, digital-analog-conversion

I am thinking about trying to make an Arduino synthesizer using the true analog output on the Due. However I would like to be able to play multiple notes at the same time on a single buzzer. Is this possible and how would I do it?

Comment: what is `buzzer`? .... is it able to produce different tones?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to add the waveforms. For example, if you want to play
pure tones (the simplest and most boring timbre), you generate a sine
wave for each of them and add them together:

```cpp
struct Note {
    float frequency;
    float phase;
    bool is_active;
} notes[MAX_NOTES];

void output_sample()
{
    static uint32_t previous_time;
    uint32_t now = micros();
    uint32_t elapsed_time = now - previous_time;
    previous_time = now;
    float output = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_NOTES; i++) {
        Note *note = &notes[i];
        if (note->is_active) {
            output += cos(note->phase);
            note->phase += 2*M_PI*note->frequency*1e-6*elapsed_time;
            if (note->phase >= 2*M_PI) {
                note->phase -= 2*M_PI;
            }
        }
    }
    analogWrite(DAC_PIN, 2048 + round(output * (2047.0 / MAX_NOTES)));
}
```

The function `output_sample()` should be called as frequently as
possible. You can change the `notes` array any time to add, remove or
change notes.

There is some room for optimization here, like:

- storing `2*M_PI*note->frequency*1e-6` as the “frequency” in order to
  save some calculations
- using a wave table instead of the `cos()` function (I don't know how
  good is the Due at transcendental math)
- replacing `elapsed_time` by a constant if you can manage to output the
  samples at a fixed rate.

---

**Edit**: I wrote “You can change the `notes` array any time to add,
remove or change notes.” Here is how to start or stop a note, i.e. to
add or remove it from the list of active notes:

```cpp
// Start a note. Returns an index to be used with stop_note(), or -1 if
// we couldn't start the note because we are already outputting the
// maximum number of simultaneous notes.
int start_note(float frequency)
{
    int i;  // index of the note in the notes[] array

    // Find a free slot in the array.
    for (i = 0; i < MAX_NOTES; i++)
        if (!notes[i].is_active) break;  // found

    // Couldn't find a free slot?
    if (i == MAX_NOTES) return -1;

    // Setup the note parameters.
    notes[i].frequency = frequency;
    notes[i].phase = 0;
    notes[i].is_active = true;
    return i;
}

// Stop the note with the given index.
void stop_note(int index)
{
    if (index >=0 && index < MAX_NOTES)
        notes[index].is_active = false;
}
```

Comment: How would I add notes here? I am not extremely familiar with structs.

Comment: @Someone: You find a cell in the array where `is_active` is `false`, and you set the desired frequency, and set `is_active` to `true`.

Comment: how would I add an item to the note array?

Answer (score 0):

Sound is nothing else than a multiple simple waves combined in to one. So, theoretically you can play as many sounds (tones) as you like on a single pin. If you want to go true analog than you probably want to use a sin wave to generate sound. However, in that case you can do the following:
Either make a function that would be capable of generating a sin wave of your desired frequency. In case of true analog this would probably be done by calculating actual sin values and using the [map()](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/math/map/) function mapping 0 - 1 to 0 - 1024 and writing to the pin. The frequency can be adjusted by changing the delay between each step of changing the voltage or [DAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital-to-analog_converter) value. However, this will not allow for multiple frequencies. 
Alternatively for multiple frequencies to be played at the same time you would need to calculate the [Fourier inversion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_inversion_theorem) of all the waves you want to play and send the results of that to the [DAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital-to-analog_converter).

Comment: And you would need to use a speaker instead of a buzzer, since they can produce a single tone at a time.

Comment: “_Fourier inversion_” is needless math jargon for what is simply the _sum_ of the tones.

Comment: @EdgarBonet yes, it's basically a sum.

Comment: How would I go about doing this?

Comment: @Someone Writing code that would preform the above described. I've included hyperlinks to help understanding what is meant and how to use it. Also, visit the https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/ page that includes much information on how to perform mathematical and logical operations in the Arduino language as well as how to control the hardware of the Arduino.

Comment: Mixing sounds is not as simple as summing them mathematically (nor summing and averaging to bring the level back down). I made that mistake once years ago, and the results were crap. Once I found a proper sound mixing function I never looked back...